# How can you create an infinite looping GIF using After Effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gif, adobe-after-effects, zoom

I tried to do this in After effects, it worked but the quality with each *zoom* decreased (I guess it's not zoom, it's something else).

So I believe we must preserve the quality, and After effects *can't* do this.

So how do people make GIFs like this? Can it be done using After effects or Photoshop or Illustrator?

[See here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WzWyaTVQ7ELy2ZQj0J2SatQeVcMehF-W)

[What I tried:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15vGnG6QY4lDTypWZu7gKbczUWAJORp5A)

EDIT:

Scott I kindly request you to remove it from duplicate. I read the answer on that question, but it is something different, or it's too hard for me to understand. I wanted to know the basics of it, instead an online solution. Also, there's not much customization (that I will need according to my project). So I believe this is a different question.

EDIT 2:

Okay, I started with a very large image (8000x8000 pixels) and quality didn't decrease. But [see this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sZNGReL3o7hg2OBI_pVchV7j48WOqcB1) output. I don't understand why the Scale speed decreases gradually. I didn't do this deliberately. The graph of animation is straight horizontal line. So what's wrong here? Further. How can I make it endless loop?

Comment: Please add examples of what you mean by quality _decrease with each zoom_. After Effects obviously can do this so maybe you have lowres assets or something else.

Comment: Please check edit. Also, the reference I given, loops infinite.

Comment: @scott can you please check edit?

Comment: The duplicate question is fine, it's the easiest way to create infinite loops like you ask. If you want to preserve quality, start with a large image.

Comment: @Luciano please check my 2nd edit.

Comment: If your output is low quality, A: your source is not large enough or B: your output is too large. If you want to loop it has to be a GIF. About the scale speed that is an entirely different problem.

Comment: No sir. I saved the same file as .GIF and it doesn't loop at all. Scale speed - What can be possible reason?

Comment: I'm not certain how this isn't a duplicate, or would require *specific troubleshooting based upon a specific file* which would be off-topic. In your last mp4 sample it would appear as though you have several iterations of the zoom in place, when all that is needed is 1 instance. I took your mp4 and chopped it down to [1 iteration with a loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbsGs.gif) - Seriously just chopped off everything after the first iteration using Photoshop. (and slowed it down).

Comment: The problem with position is due to including double end/start frames which are *slightly* out of position. You can't stop things mid-frame. So I whacked off the last frame as well and it's [much smoother](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU1O6.gif). The animation actually ends [one step before full zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asfEz.png)

Comment: @Scott the problem was I couldn't understand how to make GIFs like this. I didn't knew the concept. Your comments helped me understand the difference. Now I can agree I could somehow use that duplicate question as reference. Now, I feel it's not answered here and there as well, as I wanted to do it using After Effects. Can I change this question somehow to remove duplicate?

Comment: @Scott also (this is a different query, my problem is already solved), as I've mentioned in 2nd edit, when I tried Scale animation from 100% to 700%, the Scale speed decreased gradually. Any idea about it?

Comment: Vikas, if it's an After Effects question it's off topic as well (https://video.stackexchange.com/) -- And I'm not a "video" guy. My video skills are limited. I can't assist with After Effects.

Comment: @Scott I posted the problem here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27593/how-to-locate-right-anchor-point-location-while-making-infinite-zoom-effect-gif?noredirect=1#comment37556_27593 Nobody commented about speed :(